# Add header efficiently to a large CSV file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, script, csv

I need to add headers to a large CSV file (900+MB) but PowerShell stalls for 3 hours+ on my system and sometimes even crashes.

**Question:** *Is there a way to stream the data through instead of loading fully into memory via importing / exporting?*

I need to add a header to an existing large CSV file quickly if possible. Below are the code variants I used yet each has issues beyond my current knowledge. Any assistance or guidance is kindly appreciated.

**Slugish code**

```ps
$File = 'C:\Install.tmp\target.csv'
$filedata = import-csv $file -Header "Column 0","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5","Column 6","Column 7","Column 8","Column 9","Column 10","Column 11","Column 12","Column 13","Column 14","Column 15","Column 16"
$filedata | export-csv $file -NoTypeInformation
```

**Sluggish Code**—failed attempt which added the desired column data as new rows instead of columns)

```ps
$File = 'C:\Install.tmp\target.csv'
$Data = Get-Content -Path $File
$Header = "Column 0","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5","Column 6","Column 7","Column 8","Column 9","Column 10","Column 11","Column 12","Column 13","Column 14","Column 15","Column 16"
Set-Content $File -Value $Header
Add-Content -Path $File -Value $Data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import-csv may take huge amount a time.
Get-Content may be faster:

Generate random text csv file without header (about 1GB):

```
$path_csv = "c:\temp\random1_csv.txt"
$path_header = "c:\temp\random1_header.txt"
Measure-Command {
    "1234567890,1234567890,1234567890`r`n" * 30737418 | Set-Content -Path $path_csv 
} | select TotalSeconds # 7
```

Set header takes 13 seconds on laptop and slow nvme:

```
Measure-Command {
    "a,b,c" | Set-Content $path_header
    Get-Content -Path $path_csv -Raw | Add-Content -Path $path_header
} | select TotalSeconds # 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the input directly to the output, without going through an intermediate variable.  This is supposed to run a little faster for large files.  Try something like this:

```
$Header =  '"Column 0","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4","Column 5","Column 6","Column 7","Column 8","Column 9","Column 10","Column 11","Column 12","Column 13","Column 14","Column 15","Column 16"'     
$File = 'C:\Install.tmp\target.csv'
import-csv $file -Header $Header | export-csv $File -NoTypeInformation
```